# Dynamic datagrid Httpservice

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, real-time

I receive from the httpservice with a certain frequency a string like this:
1#3#234525234
where
row#column#value
I want to display into datagrid the above string at real time; at the moment my code displays the whole string, composed by many strings like the one above.
How can i solve the problem?
Thanks in advance

I have the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"
xmlns="*" creationComplete="srv.send()" >
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    import mx.effects.effectClasses.AddItemActionInstance;
    import mx.effects.AddItemAction;
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
    import mx.events.*;
       import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
       import mx.rpc.events.InvokeEvent;
       import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
       import mx.rpc.AsyncRequest;
       import mx.rpc.AsyncResponder;
       import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
       import mx.rpc.AbstractInvoker;
       import mx.controls.Alert;
       import mx.core.Container;
       import mx.core.IDataRenderer;
       import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridItemRenderer;
       import mx.controls.DataGrid;
       import flash.display.DisplayObject;
       [Bindable]
       public var i:Number;
       public var source:String;
       [Bindable]
       public var row:Array;
       public var column:Array;
       public var value:Array;
       public function cycle(source:String):void
       {
       var data:Array = source.split('#');
       i=0;
       for each(data in source)
       {
        row[i]=data[i]
        column[i]=data[i+1]
        value[i]=data[i+2]

        i=i+3
       }
       }

]]>
    </mx:Script>    
    <mx:HTTPService 
     id="srv" 
     url="http://10.15.20.75/server4flex/servlet/Datagen" 
     method="GET"
     /> 
    <mx:TextArea text="{cycle(srv.lastResult.toString())}" x="10" y="50" 
    width="699" height="59"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid dataProvider="{source}"  liveScrolling="true" id="dg" 
    x="10" y="117" width="621">
            <mx:columns>
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="{row[i]}"
               headerText="Riga"/>
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="{column[i]}"
               headerText="Colonna"/>
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="{value[i]}" 
               headerText="Valore"/>
            </mx:columns>
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the loop seems to be wrong, you iterate over a string `source`,  not an array. 
Secondly, your grid should bind to some properties of objects stored in a `dataProvider` (Array, ArrayCollection, etc.). So the data provider shouldn't be a string, as in your code.
Thridly, `dataField` is the name of the field of the object stored in the `dataProvider`, which value should be displayed in the grid cell.

Basicly, you need to parse your incoming string, store each row in an object and store all these objects in a collection.

So, the code should be something like:

```
[Bindable]
private var dataList:ArrayCollection;

public function cycle(source:String):void
{
var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
for(var i:int = 0; i < data.length; i += 3) {
var dataObj:Object = {row: data[i], column: data[i+1], value: data[i+2]};
ac.addItem(dataObj);
}
dataList = ac;
}

<mx:AdvancedDataGrid dataProvider="{dataList}"  liveScrolling="true" id="dg" 
    x="10" y="117" width="621">
            <mx:columns>
                        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="row"
               headerText="Riga"/>
                        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="column"
               headerText="Colonna"/>
                        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="value" 
               headerText="Valore"/>
            </mx:columns>
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i think because of the # separator omitted in you code

Comment: Yes, sure, you need to add `var data:Array = source.split('#');` before the loop.

Comment: Do you call `cycle(source)` method?

Comment: i have to call the httpservice:

so i call in dataProvider="{cycle(srv.lastResult.toString())}"

Comment: In this case, make `cycle(source)` method return ArrayCollection it's been populating.

Comment: it works but the datagrid displays all the data, i want to display one data real time at each srv.send, not the whole data

Comment: Then add to `dataList` ArrayCollection the only object you want to display. I don't know what you  mean by 'one data'

Comment: httpservice send data like this:
1#2#789# 
3#1#912# 
4#2#613#   
each x seconds;
one data means only one string (row#col#value) each x second;
if i send 20 of those single string my application displays the whole 20 strings, but i want to display in real time one by one at each srv.send